# How to configure ui-router with home/landing states and app states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have been trying to migrate to ui-router from ng-router and have encountered the following problem.

I have static pages (home, pricing, privacy policy, etc) and I have my app and its views.

I have set things up as follows:

html:

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view="content"></div>
<div ui-view="footer"></div>
```

State provider / routing

```
$stateProvider
// HOME ROUTES
.state('home', {
  url:'/',
  views: {
      'header': {
          templateUrl: 'modules/home/partials/navbar.html',
          //controller: 'HeaderController'
      },
      'content': {
          templateUrl: 'modules/home/partials/home.html',
          controller: 'HomeCtrl' 
      },
      'footer': {
          templateUrl: 'partials/footer.html',
          controller: 'FooterCtrl'
      }
  }

})
.state('home.pricing', {
  url: 'pricing',
  views: {
    'content@': {
      templateUrl: 'modules/home/partials/pricing.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('home.privacy', {
  url: 'privacy',
  views: {
    'content@': {
        templateUrl: 'modules/home/partials/privacy.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    }
  }
})
// APP ROUTES
.state('app', {
  url:'/app',
  views: {
    'header': {
        templateUrl: '/partials/menu/menu.html',
    },
    'content': {
        templateUrl: 'modules/app/partials/view1.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl',
    },
    'footer': {
        templateUrl: 'partials/footer.html',
        controller: 'FooterCtrl'
    }
  },

})

.state('app.view1', {
  url: 'view1',
  views: {
    'content@': {
        templateUrl: 'modules/app/partials/view1.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('app.view2', {
  url: 'view2',
  views: {
    'content@': {
        templateUrl: 'modules/app/partials/view2.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

Notice my basic layout is header-content-footer, but I used different headers and content between by static (home) pages and my app pages.

With this setup, example.com/#/, example.com/#/pricing, etc work
AND example.com/#/app works.

However, example.com/#/app/view1, example.com/#/app/view2 do not work and produce a failed GET request to /partials/app/view.html (which is not an html in my project).

I suspect I'm missing a basic concept here.  Any thoughts?

I'm been using the following tutorial as a guide: http://www.funnyant.com/angularjs-ui-router/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url values ought to start with a / I believe.

> url: '/view1'

Comment: That worked! Why did I need to prefix those urls with a slash, but I didn't need to do that with the home routes?

Comment: not sure exactly I imagine it has to do with how ui-router parses those urls for finding state params and such but have done similar things, it seems you can still use links that navigate to the states by name but the URL will break, but again not 100% sure